# Contador de "Me gusta" sin PHP?

Tags: jquery, html, nodejs, formularios, cookies

He estado en tarea de investigación últimamente sobre este tema en especifico y la verdad, no he dado con nada ni parecido a lo que busco, soy nuevo en esto de la programación en servidor, y por lo tanto estoy dándome la tarea de hacer un sitio limpio y sin PHP por los momentos.

Para hacer un sistema de "Likes" o un contador de clicks que se pueda almacenar o memorizar datos, es necesario utilizar Tablas Y PHP por todo lo que he visto hasta ahora, para almacenar la cifras y luego llamarlas a la vista. Mi pregunta es ¿Es esto posible con Jquery? un ejemplo de lo que estaría buscando:

```js
$(function() {
  var count = 0, countRate = 0, output = $('#output');

  setInterval(function(){ output.html(count) }, 1); // update continually

  $('#click').click(function(){ count += 1 });
  $('#autoClick').click(function(){ countRate += 1 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>

<button id="click">Click</button>
<div id="output">0</div>
```

Luego poder almacenar el resultado de alguna manera. Lo que mas me ha sonado son las cookies, de manera que según tantos ordenadores hagan click en la imagen o div, se vaya sumando y no se destruya al recargar la pagina (globalmente).

Estuve leyendo un poco en Stack sobre [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44187793/javascript-like-counter-with-memory), por lo que logro intuir tiene que ver con lo que estoy cuestionando, pero si les digo la verdad no comprendo mucho, y no por el ingles, sino por la poca explicación.

No obstante pongan la mirada en [esto](http://colorhunt.co/c/77723) he podido observar que los likes se guardan con cookies ya que al borrar estas, se elimina mi like de todas las paletas que haya dado me gusta.

Comment: ¿Quieres que los _like_ se compartan entre usuarios?

Comment: Pues es lo que quiero!

Comment: OK, entonces no se puede (al menos no sólo con jQuery). Vas a necesitar algo a nivel de servidor que guarde los valores y los sume. Cualquier cosa que hagas a nivel de cliente (sin "contador centralizado" en el servidor) no se va a compartir con otros usuarios.

Comment: Algún ejemplo con JavaScript para introducir datos al servidor con un contador?

Comment: ¿En qué lenguaje? Parece que no quieres PHP, pero hay muchos lenguajes de programación y otras muchas maneras de hacerlo diferentes. Lo que haría la pregunta demasiado amplia; sería mejor que intentaras concretar mejor qué es lo que tienes y cómo lo quieres hacer.

Comment: Se muy poco de PHP pero si hay una manera de hacerlo un poco explicativa estaría bien, si conoces un buen post o algo así me vendría de ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Debes tener claro algo y es que si deseas almacenar en el servidor estos datos, si o si debes usar lenguaje de servidor ya sea PHP para apache, Javascript para node, etc.

Si no te importa las información de los me gusta «Algo a lo que no le encuentro sentido a menos que sea una aplicación de escritorio» puedes almacenar usando `Local Storage` así los datos no se borran una ves cierras el navegador puesto que persisten.

Espero encuentres utilidad, aunque creo que te tocara incursionar en lenguaje de servidor.

Comment: Estoy trabajando con node live-server de hecho, alguna solución en JavaScript?

Comment: Entonces creo que debes buscar específicamente: "node live-server+db", "node live-server+storage". Escribo las consultas en ingles porque generalmente para estas tecnologías la información en español es aun muy pobre.

Comment: Amigo estuve buscando tu problema en google en ingles y lamentablemente no existe algo parecido existe contadores creados en JavaScript puro.

Comment: [Conexión a base de datos con nodejs Mysql](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EnCRRCvs3rM), [Tutorial para guardar información en base de datos desde node](https://www.video2brain.com/mx/tutorial/guardar-informacion-en-la-base-de-datos-de-node-js)...